# How does CoGroupByKey work with discardingFiredPanes?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Ie, if I have a GlobalWindow with a trigger that fires on every new element on each pcollection, set to discardingFiredPanes, will the CoGroupByKey fire with the lhs null when the rhs causes a fire, or with the last value from the lhs?

Given these two datasets

p1:

`|id|x1|
|1 |10|
|1 |11|
|1 |12|`

p2:

`|id|x2|
|1 |20|
|1 |21|
|1 |22|`

Should I expect:

`|id| x1 | x2 |
|1 |[10]|null|
|1 |null|[20]|
|1 |[11]|null|
|1 |null|[21]|
|1 |[12]|null|
|1 |null|[22]|`

or:

`|id| x1 | x2 |
|1 |[10]|null|
|1 |[10]|[20]|
|1 |[11]|[20]|
|1 |[11]|[21]|
|1 |[12]|[21]|
|1 |[12]|[22]|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements on the two sides of CoGroupByKey are each treated independently by the triggers system, so you will get:

```
|id| x1 | x2 |
|1 |[10]|null|
|1 |null|[20]|
|1 |[11]|null|
|1 |null|[21]|
|1 |[12]|null|
|1 |null|[22]|
```